# environment variable not accessible when start python script by pydev runner

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables, pydev

My configuration:

```
ubuntu 16.04      eclipse 4.7       python 2.7.12     PyDev 6.2.0.2017
```

When running test.py which contains blow code from PyDev:

```
print os.environ['PATH']
```

Expected values got printed out,then change 'PATH' to 'LIB_ROOT'

```
print os.environ['LIB_ROOT']
```

Got error:

```
LIB_ROOT=os.environ['LIB_ROOT']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'LIB_ROOT'
```

And same variable can be accessed from ipython console
and run test.py in bash

```
 python test.py
```

expected valued got printed out also,can anybody tell me why?